# Why do I use generic in the where clause, but the compiler still reports it not used?

Tags: rust

**Code:**

```rust
struct A<F, T, R> where F: FnOnce(T) -> R {
    foo: F,
}
```

**Error:**

```
error[E0392]: parameter `T` is never used
error[E0392]: parameter `R` is never used
```

Why do I use generic in the where clause, but the compiler still reports it not used?

Comment: If you can avoid it, I'd recommend not providing the trait bound on the struct, but rather on the impl. If you have it on the struct, you need to repeat it everywhere anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limit of the type system which currently checks the type looks directly used, and not only as a condition between constraints.

A solution is to use phantom types, which have no runtime cost:

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct A<F, T, R> where F: FnOnce(T) -> R {
    phantom: PhantomData<(T, R)>,
    foo: F,
}
```

Comment: or just `_pd: PhantomData<(R, T)>`

Comment: This will cause the drop checker to think that dropping `A` might drop values of type `T` and/or `R`. To prevent that, one can declare phantom data as `PhantomData<fn() -> (T, R)>`.

Comment: Or, even better, as `PhantomData<fn(T) -> R>`, so that the variance isn't changed.